# Cart item is not updated as per logic

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update the quantity of an added product. My logic follows as if an item is already added on the cart and the user adds it again, it just updates the quantity. But it doesn't.

As per @csisanyi I updated my code with
onCart[itemIndex].quantity += 1;  but it still shows quantity as 1

```
List<CartModel> onCart = <CartModel>[].obs;
  

  void addtoCart(CartModel item) {
    if (onCart.contains(item.productID)) {
      var itemIndex = onCart.indexOf(item);
      onCart.insert(
        itemIndex,
        CartModel(
          price: item.price,
          productID: item.productID,
          productName: item.productName,
          quantity: item.quantity + 1,
        ),
      );
      print(item.productName + item.quantity.toString());
    } else {
      onCart.add(item);
    }

  }

GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
                            CartController().addtoCart(CartModel(
                              price: productController.products[index].price,
                              productID: productController.products[index].id,
                              quantity: 1,
                              productName: productController.products[index].flavor,
                            ));
                          },
                          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined)),
```

Comment: you probably call `Get.put(CartController())` on startup, so here you must use `Get.find<CartController>().addToCart(...);` for it to work

Comment: hmm it's already initialized when the specific widget is built and i'm using that reference already.

Answer (score 1):

List .insert() adds a new element to the list at position `index`.

Instead of inserting, you should probably try

```
onCart[itemIndex].quantity += 1;
```

Comment: I did edit it but it does not update the quantity.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by editing and updating the quantity.
From your code it seems that you add a new element to your list.
The quantity of your element is initialized with 1 and when inserting it you add 1 so you should end up with a new element at position itemIndex with a quantity of 2 and the original element at itemIndex is pushed ahead to the next index.
Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right  I want to update the value of the existing item on my list and not insert a new one however I included your code in the method but it still shows 1 as the quantity.

Comment: Where does it show 1? 
Does the value change during debugging? 
Do you call setState() on the widget after modifying the element?

Comment: I just used a print statement like print(onCart[itemIndex].quantity.toString());

Comment: use the same print method before calling ```onCart[itemIndex].quantity += 1;``` to check the initial value.
if you call +=1 something should definately happen. Unless the value is final, but in that case an exception would be thrown

Comment: i added some print statements and it seems like the code breaks on the if statement and goes straight to else statement. 
The print(onCart[itemIndex].quantity.toString()); doesn't print anything

Comment: I recommend some more debugging then. But if your condition is true, than additiom should definately work :).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this sample code

```dart
import 'dart:core';

class Product {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  int? price;
  int? quantity;
  Product(this.id, this.name, this.price, this.quantity);
}

List<Product>? cart = [];

void addToCart(Product product) {
  if (cart!.any((element) => element.id == product.id)){
    product.quantity = product.quantity! + 1;
    cart?[cart!.indexOf(product)] = product;
  }else{
    cart?.add(product);
  }
  notifyUpdate(product);
}

notifyUpdate(Product product) {
  print('Added '+product.name.toString()+' to the Cart');
}

void main() {
  Product apple = Product(1, "Apple", 100, 1);
  Product banana = Product(2, "Banana", 200, 1);
  Product orange = Product(3, "Orange", 300, 1);
  Product mango = Product(4, "Mango", 400, 1);
  Product pineapple = Product(5, "Pineapple", 500, 1);
  Product watermelon = Product(6, "Watermelon", 600, 1);
  Product strawberry = Product(7, "Strawberry", 700, 1);
  Product grapes = Product(8, "Grapes", 800, 1);

  addToCart(apple);
  addToCart(banana);
  addToCart(banana);
  addToCart(orange);
  addToCart(orange);
  addToCart(orange);
  addToCart(mango);
  addToCart(pineapple);
  addToCart(watermelon);
  addToCart(watermelon);
  addToCart(strawberry);
  addToCart(grapes);
  print('\n');
  cart?.forEach((element) {
    print(element.name.toString() + ' (' + element.quantity.toString() + ')');

  });
}
```

Code Output

```sh
usamasarwar@usama Temp % dart "/Users/usamasarwar/Temp/cart.dart"
Added Apple to the Cart
Added Banana to the Cart
Added Banana to the Cart
Added Orange to the Cart
Added Orange to the Cart
Added Orange to the Cart
Added Mango to the Cart
Added Pineapple to the Cart
Added Watermelon to the Cart
Added Watermelon to the Cart
Added Strawberry to the Cart
Added Grapes to the Cart


Apple (1)
Banana (2)
Orange (3)
Mango (1)
Pineapple (1)
Watermelon (2)
Strawberry (1)
Grapes (1)
```